# Looping Through an Array of Elements and Adding a Class

Tags: jquery, loops, each

I'm trying to loop through an array of elements and add a class to each.

```
var elements = [ '#element1', '#element2' ];

$( elements ).each(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "myClass" );
});
```

Nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? The elements exist. I get no error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.each()` method is for looping over a jQuery collection. To loop over an ordinary array, use the `$.each()` function.

```js
var elements = ['#element1', '#element2'];

$.each(elements, function(i, selector) {
  $(selector).addClass("myclass");
});
```

```css
.myclass {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='element1'>Div1</div>
<div id='element2'>Div2</div>
```

Comment: This answer was the more straightforward one to implement for my use case. Thanks Barmar!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery objects only accepts an array of Element objects in an array. As such you could amend your array to contain Element objects, like this:

```js
var elements = [document.querySelector('#element1'), document.querySelector('#element2')];
$(elements).addClass("myClass");
```

```css
.myClass { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element1">Element1</div>
<div id="element2">Element2</div>
```

This is obviously far from ideal as it's more verbose than necessary and also rather redundant.

An alternative would be to build a valid selector string from the array of strings in your example. This could be done using `join()`:

```js
var elements = ['#element1', '#element2'];
$(elements.join(',')).addClass("myClass");
```

```css
.myClass { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element1">Element1</div>
<div id="element2">Element2</div>
```

Note that in either case the explicit `each()` loop is not required; most jQuery methods will implicitly loop over every element in the jQuery object, as `addClass()` does here.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple selectors have to be seperated by `,` and not as strings in an array.

```js
var elements = '#element1, #element2';

$( elements ).each(function() {
  $(this).addClass( "myClass" );
});
```

```css
.myClass { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='element1'>Div1</div>
<div id='element2'>Div2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through an array of selectors, not elements. jQuery will call each iterate with string selector as context. But it will be autoboxed into `String` object. You can convert it back to primitive string by calling `toString`.

Or use the second argument instead of `this`

```
$(elements).each(function(_, selector) {
  $(selector).addClass( "myClass" );
});
```

```js
var elements = ['#element1', '#element2'];

$(elements).each(function() {
  console.log(typeof this, this instanceof String); // object true
  $(this.toString()).addClass( "myClass" );
});
```

```css
.myClass { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='element1'>Div1</div>
<div id='element2'>Div2</div>
```